# emacs auto-complete-c-headers and closing brackets

Tags: auto-complete-mode, header-line

I'm new to Emacs. I followed a tutorial for Emacs as IDE for C/C++ but there are steps that do not work fully for me: the auto-complete for c-headers.

I installed yasnippet and auto-complete for C/C++ headers.

1) I get the normal auto-complete behavior for `#include <stdio.h` but `>` closing hook is not added even if I type tab on `h` .

2) And some functions (I don't know how many) aren't called even with 
   their headers.

Other posts, particularly [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22570/12950), helped me to solve an issue about `#include <float`  when  is not completed with `.h`, now it works but as alwas tab on `h` does not add `>`.

So after changing my `.emacs` from the link above , `#include <ctype.h>`  doesn't call at least `isdig`  knowing that I want `isdigit` ...
And for `getchar` it doesn't add  `()`wherease for  while, for loops it works fine...

Here is my new `.emacs` after following the link above.

```el
; start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
;add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
;initialize package.el
(package-initialize)
;start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
;do default config for auto-complete
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
;start yasineppet with emacs
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)
;let's define a function which initializes auto-complete-c-headers and gets called for c/c++ headers hooks
(defun my:ac-c-header-init ()
  (require 'auto-complete-c-headers)
  (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-c-headers)
  (setq achead:include-directories
  (append '("/usr/include/c++/5"
        "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
        "/usr/include/c++/5/backward"
        "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include"
        "/usr/local/include"
        "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed"
        "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu")
        achead:include-directories)))
;now let's call this function from c/c++ hooks
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my:ac-c-header-init)
```

Something is missing ?
The path for headers comes from `gcc -xc++ -E -v -`

```
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Comment: I usually use yasnippet to insert #include<|> or #include"|", where | indicates the cursor position, then auto-complete kicks in when I press TAB, optionally after I have typed a few leading characters. In this way I've never run into your current issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you would accomplish this with `auto-complete` but I do know that you can do all of this and more with `company-mode`, `company-irony`, `company-irony-c-headers`, and `irony`. You can find all of them on [MELPA](https://melpa.org/).

I'll walk you through my `init.el` file and you can make the relevant changes in yours accordingly. **However, you should read the guides of the respective packages on their website instead of just copying mine.**

First, enable `company-mode` using

```el
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-company-mode)
```

The following are some optimizations that I made. You may or may not want them.

```el
(setq company-idle-delay 0.5)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
(setq company-selection-wrap-around t)
(setq company-show-numbers t)
(setq company-tooltip-align-annotations t)
```

The following line enables `irony-mode`.

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'irony-mode)
```

I found the following code [here](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) and this is supposed to replace the default completion options with the options that `irony-mode` would provide.

```el
(defun my-irony-mode-hook ()
  (define-key irony-mode-map [remap completion-at-point]
    'irony-completion-at-point-async)
  (define-key irony-mode-map [remap complete-symbol]
    'irony-completion-at-point-async))
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook #'my-irony-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'irony-mode-hook #'irony-cdb-autosetup-compile-options)
```

Add `company-irony-c-headers` and `company-irony` to the list of backends that `company-mode` uses.

```el
(eval-after-load 'company
  '(add-to-list
    'company-backends '(company-irony-c-headers company-irony)))
```

Comment: it doessn't works,  after installations nothing is completed like #include <stdio ....    When I open a  file.c  it shows me : Company backend 'company-clang' could not be initialized:
Company found no clang executable     While I had already uninstalled  clang, and I have nothing of clang in my .emacs  but somefiles from clang in usr/lib  or usr/hare are still there don't know if it can make conflict with new installations ...  sudo apt-get remove clang  : clang isn't installed nothing to delet...   I have to install clang to not have those errors, but no completion again ...

Comment: @F.A You should read the guides of the respective packages on their website. From what I understood, you haven't installed `clang` and that is the reason `company` is giving you errors. You should install `clang` and try again.

Comment: already done and no completion as I said " I have to install clang to not have those errors, but no completion again ..."

Comment: Can you give the output of `clang --version` and `clang++ --version` just to check what it says if this is still a problem?

Comment: Didn't work for me either.  This whole thing is a confusing mess.  God forbid the developers of this crap actually document something properly.

Comment: Doesn't work is how I would describe my efforts trying multiple solutions, spending most time on irony-mode, documentation is pretty light, there's some steps on installing irony but it required a lot of redos and errors and looking at other sources. And then it doesn't really explain how you are supposed to get a compiler database and all that, I'm just left guessing and experimenting, I dunno if I am just bad at reading docs and sucks

Comment: Honestly what I wanted I found in sublime text, it worked exactly like I wanted it, that's a nice app. VSCode probably does all this as well too. But I wanted to start with something simpler and more nitty gritty since I did not want an IDE but work directly with an editor and GCC and learn makefiles. But it feels like I can't work with emacs even, real confidence killer